# Infix operator with missing argument

Tags: function, haskell, infix-notation

Is it possible with Haskell to have an operator (infix function) working with a missing argument ? (rather like `-` meaning a subtraction or a negative sign)

For example, I have this operator :

```
data1 <*> data2
```

Is it possible to make it work with a default value if first argument is omitted ?

```
<*> data2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. On the other hand, you could perfectly well define a different operation that provides the default argument, e.g.

```
withDef data2 = {- your default value -} <*> data2
```

If you really want to use a name that would otherwise be an operator, you can still name this partially applied function with an operator name:

```
($<*>) data2 = {- default value -} <*> data2
```

It can be used prefix, as in `($<*>) data2`, or postfix with appropriate GHC extensions, as in `(data2 $<*>)`. The parentheses are not optional.